# How to show google map when user hovers over static image in html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, onhover

I would like to know to show a google map in a lightbox when a user clicks on an image. 
For Example:-

```
<img src="map_icon.png" alt="hover over image to show corresponding map" onclick="run_map_function();" />
```

I would really like to know how to do this. Any help will be much appreciated! Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure if it possible to use a lightbox plugin, but try the JqueryUi dialog instead, it's easy to use and can be set in seconds
Take a look at my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/theodore/trnZS/49/

Comment: Thank you for your effort! Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Does the map need to be interactive?  if not, you should look at using the static maps api:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Basically, you can use the static maps api to generate an image of the location you want to view, like here: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false

If you need an interactive map, then I suggest using an iFrame (which would mean creating a separate page for the map).  You should easily be able to show an iframe from your lightbox.